# Ajax call not returning error

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have some ajax code on the client side like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "frmPNList.aspx/ChangeGroupOfUSNs",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //data: '{strNewUSN: "' + usn.value + '", strURNs: "' + id[1] + '", strDatasetName: "' + id[2] + '", strCon: "' + $("#<%=fieldGenieConnectionString.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
                data: '{strNewUSN: "' + usn.value + '", arrayURNDataset: ' + JSON.stringify(strURNDataset) + ', strCon: "' + connectionstring.value + '", strUserNameLocal: "' + username.value + '"}',
                //data: '{strNewUSN: 9, strURNs: 1, strDatasetName: 2}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess(),
                error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
                    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText
                    alert("there was an error changing the USN of the group: " + errorMessage);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert('there was an error changing the USN of the group.')

                }
            });

            function OnSuccess() {
                return function () {

                }
            }
            //end of AJAX call
```

and on the server side:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Sub ChangeGroupOfUSNs(ByVal strNewUSN As String, ByVal arrayURNDataset As String, ByVal strCon As String, ByVal strUserNameLocal As String)
Try
            Throw New Exception
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

The failure message is not called.  Why is this?

Comment: You catch the exception so its killed and does not propagate up; the server does not recognize an error so returns 200 success instead of a 500 error code.

Comment: I don't understand too much about vb web methods but, shouldn't you throw / return the exception to the front end or something? or maybe just return http:500? looking at the code looks like your request never replies anything when it goes into the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Failure only gets triggered when something goes wrong with the request itself (error 404, error 500, etc). It does not return PHP/ASP errors.

If you want to check PHP/ASP errors you'll have to make that yourself (in the done function you can create some if statements).